# Interpretation of moment generating function as $t$ varies?

Tags: statistics

Apologies if my question is primitive. What is the physical interpretation of moment generating function for varying 't'? In almost all places I read about it, the $r^{th}$ moment about the origin is defined by taking the $r^{th}$ derivative and substituting $t=0$. The moment about any other location $m$ is defined as,

$$E[e^{t(X-m)}]=e^{-tm}E[e^{tX}]$$

but it is still evaluated at the origin. I can see the physical interpretation at a location $m$ being the mean, variance etc. around $m$, but what does it mean as $t$ varies, in terms of physical/statistical interpretation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: At the end of the day, the MGF is a generating function. As a rule of thumb, that term means an auxiliary function which has relatively little significance *per se* but can be used to generate some other quantity (usually through the coefficients of its series expansion). That said, you can interpret the growth rate of the moment generating function as $t$ moves towards $+\infty$ (resp. $-\infty$) as a measure of the positive (resp. negative) tail of the distribution.

Comment: (Cont.) For example, the positive tail of $X$ is "asymptotically fatter" than that of any exponential distribution with rate parameter greater than $\min \{ t \geq 0 : E[e^{tX}]=+\infty \}$. And if that set is empty, then the positive tail is "asymptotically thinner" than any exponential distribution. As for another fruitful application of the concept, take a look at Cramer's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Can it also be inferred as various realizations underlying the random process that generates X in the first place?